# How to use jQuery to select an image being hovered over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## Outline

My intention is for the user to hover over an image, and an overlaying div with reduced opacity will appear over the top of it. The overlaying laying div has a height of 0px and when hovered it should increase the height value to exactly half of the image height.

The hover function is working but I think this line is wrong:

## EDIT

After trying to log the curHeight variable (which was 'undefined') i think this line must be creating the issue:

```
var curHeight = landingImg.clientHeight;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="landing-images">
    <div class="leftLanding">
        <div class="imageCover">
        </div>
        <img class="landingImage" src="assets/landingIMG1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="rightLanding">
        <div class="imageCover">
        </div>
        <img class="landingImage" src="assets/landingIMG1.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".landingImage").hover(function () {
        console.log("hover works");
        var landingImg = $(this);
        var curHeight = landingImg.clientHeight;
        $(this).closest('.imageCover').css("height", curHeight / 2);
    }, function () {
        $(this).closest('.imageCover').css("height", "0px");
    });
```

Comment: `var landingImg = $(this);` should definitely be the image you are hovering over. I don't think that's the issue. Are you using the inspector to see exactly what is being triggered? Are you sure that `closest` is returning the expected element?

Comment: @Cfreak By the looks of my HTML I think he right elelment should be getting selected, maybe it's an issue with the curHeight / 2?

Comment: possibly. Without running the full code myself it's kind of hard to tell. I know I use `$(this)` to get the current element all the time.

Comment: @Cfreak I've just tried using console.log to display the curHeight and apparently it' undefined so i'm guessing that's the problem. Should I parseInt perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.siblings()` instead and you must add **width** to div or it won't show, and use `.height()` and `.width()` to get the height and the width of the image

```js
$(".landingImage").hover(function () {

        var landingImg = $(this);
        var curHeight = landingImg.height();
        var curWidth = landingImg.width();
        $(this).siblings('.imageCover').css("height", curHeight / 2);
        $(this).siblings('.imageCover').css("width", curWidth);
    }, function () {
        $(this).siblings('.imageCover').css("height", "0px");
        $(this).siblings('.imageCover').css("width",  "0px");
    });
```

```css
.leftLanding,
.rightLanding {
  position: relative;
}

.imageCover {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 111;
  opacity:.5;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="landing-images">
  <div class="leftLanding">
    <div class="imageCover">
    </div>
    <img class="landingImage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="rightLanding">
    <div class="imageCover">
    </div>
    <img class="landingImage" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Chiller can you explain why .siblings had to be used and worked instead of .closest? I can't understand why it wasn't working

Comment: this is the documentation it explains better than i wil, hope it helps :) https://api.jquery.com/siblings/  ,  https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Thank you @Chiller

Answer (score 1):

[`.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) is a DOM property.

Change

```
var curHeight = landingImg.clientHeight;
```

To

```
var curHeight = landingImg.height();
```

Or

```
var curHeight = this.clientHeight;
```

Comment: Thank you @Andreas this calculated the height correctly. However I used the answer below to make the div appear.